# Select the "Merge into [radio-button]" [optionbutton] and hit Retag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[optionbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optionbutton) has no wiki, is strictly synonymous with [radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-button), and all of its 14 questions are validly taggable as `radio-button`. Admittedly, as an old VB4 hack, I prefer the former terminology, but that battle appears to be lost on SO, so let's merge these in.